# Use browseURL but let URL be variable from some point

Tags: r, dataframe, url, browser, browse-url

I'm trying to use the browseURL() command for opening different filenames of one website from my data-frame. My problem is, I don't have the full URL inside my columns but rather just the part after the hostname (the filename). Now, can I somehow adjust the command so that it allows the second part of the URL-string to be a variable, for example as in

browseURL("http://www.example-website.com

*this is where I'm looking for help*

example_exampledata[1, "exampleText"]")

For better understanding: posts_exampledata is my data-frame on which I'm trying to address the first line and the column "exampleText", which contains a filename such as /forum/exapmle-theme/12345-what-is-example.html

Any tips and hints are highly appreciated, and please excuse the potential unclarity of this post since I'm very new to R and english isn't my native language.

Comment: Please see `?paste0`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `paste0()` function. You would be able to directly paste the variable URL to your `browseURL()` function.

Example of `paste0` :

```
# the paste0() function in R

paste0("one", "two", "three")
[1] "onetwothree"

url <- "www.url.com"

paste0("/some/kind/of_URL")
[1] "/some/kind/of_URL"

paste0(url, "/some/kind/of_URL")
[1] "www.url.com/some/kind/of_URL"
```

This function should allow you to do what your seeking for.

Edit : Sorry noticed **ismirsehregal** comment.

Comment: @M.P. Glad it work! I suggest you take a look at the ``paste()`` function which is alsmost the same. Those functions can be really usefull.